# Kinect 360 point cloud resolution increase - is it possible with more infrared projectors in the room?

Tags: kinect, point-clouds

If I scatter more infrared points around the room from separate infrared laser speckle projectors, and in doing so increase the point cloud resolution spread over objects in the room, will this result in a higher resolution 3d scan captured by the infrared camera on the Kinect 360? Or are there limitations on how much point cloud data the IR camera and/or Kinect software/hardware can process?

Answer (score 1):

Found this paper which answered my question:

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~hema/rgbd-workshop-2014/papers/Alhwarin.pdf